# jquery isotope not working with infinite stroller

Tags: jquery-isotope, jquery-lazyload

I have a grid of products set up with the isotope plugin, the products are paginated and loaded in on the scroll with the infinite scroll plugin. This works fine, but as there are so many products we've also added a number of filters, again this filters work great but when combined with the infinite scroll I run into some problems, as when I initiate the filter, if the results aren't on the first page, you then have to wait for all the pages to load before any results are shown. 
So my question is, is there a more sophisticated way of combining both the isotope filtering and infinite scroll?

Comment: More sophisticated than what? You haven't posted any code for us to know what your current problem is.

Comment: //ISOTOPE FUNCTION - FILTER PORTFOLIO FUNCTION
 $(window).load(function(){
  $portfolio = $('.portfolio-items');
  $portfolio.isotope({
   itemSelector : 'li',
   layoutMode : 'fitRows'
  });
  $portfolio_selectors = $('.portfolio-filter >li>a');
  $portfolio_selectors.on('click', function(){
   $portfolio_selectors.removeClass('active');
   $(this).addClass('active');
   var selector = $(this).attr('data-filter');
   $portfolio.isotope({ filter: selector });
   return false;
  });
 });